# How to 'subscribe to'/receive Web Push Notification programmatically (e.g. python or nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, browser, push-notification

I am trying to find a way to 'subscribe to'/receive push notification programmatically, e.g. using nodejs or python. So, I know there is an update to the site, and then I could kick off other tasks.

I am not too sure which technical term(s) I should look into. Could you point me to the right direction? Is there any npm or package that could do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Receive where exactly? Please elaborate what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Receive from any site that is pushing.

Comment: Look into webhooks.